# Speedup of reduce function?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, inequalities

I tried to run this $15$ variable feasibility linear programming to see what the solution looks like. Unfortunately it is taking too much time on my laptop. Is there a way to speed it up? Any tips will help.

```
  Reduce[{0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 0 <= d <= 1, 
   0 <= e <= 1, 0 <= f <= 1, a + b + c == d + e + f == 2, 
   0 <= k <= Min[a, d], 0 <= l <= Min[a, e], 
   0 <= m <= Min[a, f], 0 <= p <= Min[b, d], 
   0 <= q <= Min[b, e], 0 <= r <= Min[b, f], 
   0 <= s <= Min[c, d], 0 <= t <= Min[c, e], 
   0 <= u <= Min[c, f], 
   l + m + k + p + q + r + s + t + u == 4}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, k, l, m,
   p, q, r, s, t, u}]
```

Comment: There is a specific function `LinearProgramming`.

Comment: Why do you want reduce to rewrite the conditions that defines the feasible region? What's the problem with those you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions of

```
Reduce[{
  a + b + c == 2,
  d + e + f == 2,
  0 <= k <= Min[a, d, (a + d)/2],
  0 <= l <= Min[a, e, (a + e)/2],
  0 <= m <= Min[a, f, (a + f)/2],
  0 <= p <= Min[b, d, (b + d)/2],
  0 <= q <= Min[b, e, (b + e)/2],
  0 <= r <= Min[b, f, (b + f)/2],
  0 <= s <= Min[c, d, (c + d)/2],
  0 <= t <= Min[c, e, (c + e)/2],
  0 <= u <= Min[c, f, (c + f)/2],
  l + m + k + p + q + r + s + t + u == 4}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, k, l, m, p, q, r, s, t, u}]
```

translate to conditions with the forms `matrix.var ≥ vec`, `matrix.var = vec` and
`matrix.var ≤ vec` with the following matrices and vectors

```
(* Greater than 0 *)
mat1 = PadLeft[IdentityMatrix[{9, 15}][[;; 9, ;; 9]], {9, 15}];
vec1 = ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 9];

(* Equal to 2 *)
mat2 = PadRight[{{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}}, {2, 15}];
vec2 = ConstantArray[{2, 0}, 2];

(* Equal to 4 *)
mat3 = {Join[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, ConstantArray[1, 9]]};
vec3 = {{4, 0}};

(* Less than inequalities *)
With[{kToU = PadLeft[IdentityMatrix[{9, 15}][[;; 9, ;; 9]], {9, 15}],
      aToC = PadRight[ArrayFlatten[Evaluate[DiagonalMatrix[{#, #, #}]] &[{{1}, {1}, {1}}]], {9, 15}],
       def = Join[#, #, #] &[PadRight[RotateLeft[IdentityMatrix[{3, 6}], {0, 3}], {3, 15}]]},
  mat4 = Join[kToU - aToC, kToU - def, kToU - (aToC + def)/2]];
vec4 = ConstantArray[{0, -1}, 27];
```

and the remaining inequalites are

```
varMinMax = PadRight[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 6], 15, {{-∞, ∞}}];
```

To minimize a linear combination of the variables, evaluate this code:

```
LinearProgramming[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 15],
 Join[mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4],
 Join[vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4],
 varMinMax]
```

Comment: is it quick now? Also I am not minimizing (I am doing feasibility).

Comment: How is the output to be interpreted?

Comment: Sorry could you comment where exactly are you doing inequalities?

Comment: @Turbo I construct a matrix and a vector such that `matrix.vars ≥ vec` are the same inequalities as those you wrote. What I call `vec` is actually `n,2`-dimensional. The second column indicates whether the LHS (`mat.vars`) should be less, equal of greater than the RHS (first column of `vec`).

Comment: it works I am just trying to understand your code so I can generalize it. you dont use matrix.var ≥ vec in code. What does join do? some kind of implicit inequality? BTW the o/p is pretty fast.

Comment: For `k <= Min[a, d, (a + d)/2]` the matrix has 3 rows. One for each of `k <= a`, `k <= d` and `k <= (a + d)/2`